# Copy lines from file to char *array[]?

Tags: arrays, c, file, io

Hi need a little bit of help here. I have a file with 5 lines and I want to put this lines into an array of type `char *lines[5];` but I can't figure it out why the following isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("name.txt", "r");
    char *str;
    char *list[5];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(str, 100, fp) != NULL) // read line of text
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        strcpy(list[i], str);
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `list[i]` is an uninitialized pointer. You need to make it point somewhere with `malloc` or `strdup`.

Comment: Of create an array of *arrays*, like `char list[5][100];`.

Comment: By the way you have the same pointer problem with `str`: It's an uninitialized pointer, its value (where it points) is *indeterminate* (and you should look at it as garbage).

Comment: You should probably take a few steps back, and pick up your text-book to read more about pointers and arrays.

Comment: The first argument to `fgets` is the location where `fgets` will write data.  `str` is not initialized, so you are not giving `fgets` a valid place to write.

Comment: And you should think about what happens if the user enters more than `5` strings. You need to add a check for that so you don't go out of bounds of the `list` array.

Comment: (1) `char *str;` --> `char str[100];` (2) `strcpy(list[i], str);` --> `list[i] = strdup(str);` With (1), cleaner is: `fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)`

Comment: Finally, with `list` properly initialized or an array of arrays you don't really need the temporary `str` variable or any string copying, you can just read directly into `list[i]`. As in `for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5 && fgets(list[i], sizeof list[i], stdin) != NULL; ++i) { printf("%s\n", list[i]); }` Or if you just want to print the input you don't need `list` at all: `char str[100]; while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL) { printf("%s\n", str); }`

Comment: The forward declaration of function `lines` does not appear related to your question. If it is irrelevant, it should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters stated, you need to create an array (which is nothing more than a space in the memory) of a sufficient size to store your string. One approach to solve your problems is the following, note the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int lines(FILE *file); //try to format the code according to some standard
    int main(void) {
        FILE *fp = fopen("name.txt", "r");
        char list[5][100]; //make sure you allocate enough space for your message

// for loop is more elegant than while loop in this case, 
// as you have an index which increases anyway.
// also, you can make sure that files with more than 5 lines 
// do not break your program.
        for(int i = 0; i<5 ;++i ) 
        {
            if(fgets(list[i], 100, fp) == NULL){
               break;
            }
            //list[i] is already a string, you don't need an extra copy
            printf("%s", list[i]);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You could even include the `fgets` call into the condition in your loop. `for (int i = 0; i < 5 && fgets(list[i], 100, fp) != NULL; ++i ) { printf("%s", list[i]); }`